# Reading DBF generates duplicates

Tags: c#, dbf

I'm currently building a local DBF converter using C#. Current library is the FastDBF library. I currently have tested the code below and dump the DBF contents into a text file. The total rows that is showing in MS Excel does not match the rows generated by the DBF library. See below photo.

[image]

This is the piece of code I have to read and write the DBF file contents

```
 var odbf = new DbfFile(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
 odbf.Open(Path.Combine(this.pathWithFile), FileMode.Open)
 var ofs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(this.currentDirectory, "filesource.txt"), FileMode.Create);
 var osw = new StreamWriter(ofs, Encoding.Default);
 var orec = new DbfRecord(odbf.Header);
 for (int i = 0; i < odbf.Header.RecordCount; i++)
 {
    if (!odbf.Read(i, orec))
       break;
    osw.WriteLine("index: " + orec.RecordIndex + ": " + orec);
 }
 osw.Flush();
 osw.Close();
```

The number of rows read differ from the generated result 28057 vs 28307. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Try to check if record that is read is not deleted (`orec.IsDeleted`). AFAIK dbf file holds all earlier deleted records, just marks them as deleted.

Comment: @Quercus I both tried to place into an If statement and print the IsDeleted flag, all rows appear to have it as "False". No change in the number of rows